# Collective Majority?

Tags: meaning

I read this transcript from PBS Brief but Spectacular video clip:

> In 1970, the population of the U.S. was 88 percent white. By 2010,
>   that had dropped to 75 percent white, and it's estimated that, by
>   2050, that number be 47 percent. So, for the first time, **we will be a
>   collective majority.** No single ethnicity or culture will be in
>   majority in this country. And that's already true for the population
>   under 18.

(emphasis mine)
[NPR - Dana Mortenson](https://www.pbs.org/newshour/brief/250060/dana-mortenson)

First, I'm not sure if by "we will be" she means as a group, white people will be a collective majority or as a nation we will be a collective majority. Secondly, I have no idea of what **collective majority** even means.

Comment: I think she means that all races and ethnicities will constitute the "collective majority."

Comment: *Collective majority*, in terms of US demographics, refers all non-whites. Whites have been a simple majority across the board until recently. The "we wiil be" reference is a bit awkward, but evidently is meant to refer to Americans in total, as the author explains in the next sentence.

Comment: It would seem that the **we will be** refers to the entire US population and not any single group within it. Especially since the group she is CEO of, is to focus students to; "...leverage diversity in the classroom as an asset."

Comment: @PhilSweet so the collection of minorities is the collective majority if it is larger then the (single group type)  majority?

Comment: The term "minority majority" is one I've heard frequently--rather than "collective majority."  Here's an article that tries to figure out the categories of the U.S. Census. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_and_ethnicity_in_the_United_States_Census#2010_Census

Comment: The implication is that by saying **we**, she belongs to a minority, the "collection" of all of which will finally make up more than 50% of the population. However, she fails to identify her race anywhere, so the statement simply becomes puzzling. If what she really meant to say is that there will be no race with a simple majority, she should have said that. Otherwise, she misused **collective majority**. She can't mean *everyone* because it would *always have been* everyone, and whites dropping below 50% would have no affect on that (since they are part of "everyone").